# Laravel Nova error base table or view not found

Tags: laravel-6, laravel-nova

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'newsim_yrpixakb.action_events' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into
>   `action_events` (`batch_id`, `user_id`, `name`, `actionable_type`,
>   `actionable_id`, `target_type`, `target_id`

Laravel Nova is trying to use the tenant database to add action events information.

I have a multiple client app, and it works like this. All clients login at example.com, and based on their information, they only see what they need to see.  In the main system database, I have Users, Pages, etc. where clients only see Users Resource and only users associated with their org_id

Each client has a different database to view their members, events, items tables. I change databases with this code in each model.  The auth()->user()->dbname is used here so that super admins can move between clients for client support.

```php
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    if (auth()->user()->dbname) {
        Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', auth()->user()->dbname);
        $this->connection = 'tenant';
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to add a new client, then add a database and migrate. I can do this from a custom artisan command but would like to use the add Client button in nova. So I've added this to the User model, and all works except the error message.

```php
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($user) {
        $user->active = 1;
        $user->org_id = self::nextOrgId();
        $user->dbname = $user->createNewDatabaseName();
        $user->aps_token = Str::random(32);
    });
    static::created(function ($user) {
        $user->createNewClientDatabase();
    });
    static::updating(function ($user) {
        $user->syncClientFields();
    });
}

public function createNewClientDatabase()
{
    $systemDB = env('DB_DATABASE');
    $charset = config("database.connections.mysql.charset", 'utf8mb4');
    $collation = config("database.connections.mysql.collation", 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci');
    $query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $this->dbname CHARACTER SET $charset COLLATE $collation;";

    try {
        \DB::statement($query);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $systemDB);
    \DB::purge('mysql');

    Config::set('database.connections.tenant.database', $this->dbname);
    \DB::purge('tenant');
    Artisan::call('migrate', [
        '--database' => 'tenant',
        '--path' => 'database/NewClient'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Hi, @dmgd, how did you get around this, I am in pretty much the same situation where I run migrations to create tenant tables using a --path parameter and this doesn't seem to then run nova's own migrations which is what creates the action_events table. Any help/pointers would be appreciated

Comment: @Obi I had to add a copy of the action_event table to the tenant migrations. I tried stopping action events but it never worked.

Answer (score 0):

Manually deleting all tables from the user schema and rerunning the migration solved my problem.